# Python tkinter binding a function with multiple parameters

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments

I have a general question that I can't really find an answer to so hopefully you guys can help. I have a function that takes 3 parameters, below is an example of what I have.

```
def someFunction(self, event, string):

   do stuff ..

self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.someFunction("Hello"))
```

When I run this, I get an error saying that I passed someFunction 2 arguments instead of 3. I'm not sure why ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you're binding the **result** of `someFunction` (or trying to anyway).  This fails because when python tries to get the result of `someFunction`, it calls it only passing 1 argument (`"Hello"`) when `someFunction` really expects 2 explicit arguments.  You probably want something like:

```
self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>',lambda event: self.someFunction(event,"Hello"))
```

This binds a new function (which is created by `lambda` and wraps around `self.someFunction`) which passes the correct arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Or,

```
def someFunction(self, string):
   def fn(*arg)
      print string
   return fn


self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>",self.someFunction("Hello!"))
```